# Best way to bin (into categorical values), based on multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to bin using values from two columns into another column.

Supposed the following is my pandas df:

```
data = {'material':['Matl_A', 'Matl_B', 'Matl_B', 'Matl_A'], 
        'strength':[10, 20, 30, 100]  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

So my df is:

```
  material   strength  
 ---------- ---------- 
  Matl_A           10  
  Matl_B           20  
  Matl_B           30  
  Matl_A          100
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
  material   strength    grade
 ---------- ---------- ---------
  Matl_A           10       1
  Matl_B           20       4
  Matl_B           80       5
  Matl_A          100       2
```

What would be the best way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I used Michael Gardner's answer below and expanded it because we have lots of materials. Hopefully, this revision provides a clearer picture. What would be a more elegant way to approach this if I have like 20 material with different conditional ranges that I need to bin:

```py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    strength = np.random.randint(low=1, high=30, size=20)
    material = ['matl_a', 'matl_b', 'matl_b', 'matl_a', 'matl_d',
                'matl_b', 'matl_d', 'matl_a', 'matl_a', 'matl_b',
                'matl_a', 'matl_b', 'matl_e', 'matl_a', 'matl_c',
                'matl_b', 'matl_c', 'matl_a', 'matl_a', 'matl_b']

    data = {'material':material, 
            'strength':strength } 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    def grading(df):
        if df['material'] == 'matl_a':
            if 0 <= df['strength'] <=10:
                return 1
            elif 11 <= df['strength'] <= 20:
                return 2
            elif 21 <= df['strength'] <= 30:
                return 3
            elif 31 <= df['strength'] <= 40:
                return 4
            else:
                return 5
        elif df['material'] == 'matl_b':
            if 0 <= df['strength'] <=10:
                return 6
            elif 11 <= df['strength'] <= 20:
                return 7
            elif 21 <= df['strength'] <= 30:
                return 8
            elif 31 <= df['strength'] <= 40:
                return 9
            else:
                return 10
        elif df['material'] == 'matl_c':
            if 0 <= df['strength'] <=10:
                return 11
            elif 11 <= df['strength'] <= 20:
                return 12
            elif 21 <= df['strength'] <= 30:
                return 13
            elif 31 <= df['strength'] <= 40:
                return 14
            else:
                return 15        
        else:
            if 0 <= df['strength'] <=10:
                return 16
            elif 11 <= df['strength'] <= 20:
                return 17
            elif 21 <= df['strength'] <= 30:
                return 18
            elif 31 <= df['strength'] <= 40:
                return 19
            else:
                return 20

    df['grade'] = df.apply(grading, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN:

```
data = {'material':['Matl_A', 'Matl_B', 'Matl_B', 'Matl_A'], 
        'strength':[10, 20, 80, 100] } 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def grading(df):
    if df['material'] == 'Matl_A':
        if 5 <= df['strength'] <= 10:
            return 'A'
        elif 11 <= df['strength'] <= 20:
            return 'B'
        else:
            return 'C'
    elif 10 <= df['strength'] <= 50:
        return 'A'
    elif 50 <= df['strength'] <= 100:
        return 'B'
    else:
        return 'C'

df['grade'] = df.apply(grading, axis=1)

df.head()
```

OUT:

```
| material | strength | grade |
|----------|----------|-------|
| Matl_A   | 10       | A     |
| Matl_B   | 20       | A     |
| Matl_B   | 80       | B     |
| Matl_A   | 100      | C     |
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.select`

```
a = df.material.eq('Matl_A')
b = df.material.eq('Matl_B')

df['grade'] = np.select([a & df.strength.between(5,10),
                         a & df.strength.between(11,20),
                         b & df.strength.between(10,50),
                         b & df.strength.between(50,100)],
                         ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                         default='C')
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the grade definitions in a df.

```
grades = pd.DataFrame([
    ('Matl_A', 5, 'A'),
    ('Matl_A', 11, 'B'),
    ('Matl_A', 21, 'C'),
    ('Matl_B', 10, 'A'),
    ('Matl_B', 51, 'B'),
    ('Matl_B', 101, 'C'),
], columns=('material', 'strength', 'grade'))
grades = grades.sort_values(['strength'])
```

And then use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
pd.merge_asof(df, grades, on='strength', by='material')
```

The grade definitions can be loaded from external source (css or db etc.).
This can handle large number of materials and grade slabs without mess.